# What is the complexity (Big-O) of this algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o, permutation

I'm fairly familiar with algorithm analysis and can tell the Big-O of most algorithms I work with. But I've been stuck for hours unable to come up with the Big-O for this code I write.

Basically it's a method to generate permutations for a string. It works by making each character in the string the first character and combine it with the permutations of the substring less that character (recursively).

If I put in the code to count the number of iterations, I've got something between O(N!) and O(N^N). But I couldn't figure out how to analyse it mentally. Any suggestion is much appreciated!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Permutation {

   int count = 0;

   List<String> findPermutations(String str) {
      List<String> permutations = new ArrayList<String>();
      if (str.length() <= 1) { 
         count++;
         permutations.add(str);
         return permutations;
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
         String sub = str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(i + 1);
         for (String permOfSub : findPermutations(sub)) {
            count++;
            permutations.add(str.charAt(i) + permOfSub);
         }
      }
      return permutations;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      for (String s : new String[] {"a", "ab", "abc", "abcd", "abcde", "abcdef", "abcdefg", "abcdefgh"}) {
         Permutation p = new Permutation();
         p.findPermutations(s);
         System.out.printf("Count %d vs N! %d%n", p.count, fact(s.length()));
      }
   }

   private static int fact(int i) {
      return i <= 1 ? i : i * fact(i-1);
   }
}
```

**Edit 1:** add test program

**Edit 2:** add `count++` in base case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recurrence equation: `T(n) = n*(T(n-1) + (n-1)!), T(1) = 1` where `n = str.length`.

WolframAlfa says that the solution is n*(1)<sub>n</sub> i.e., `n*n!`.

The above assumes that all string operations are O(1). Otherwise if the cost of `String sub = ...` and `permutations.add(str.charAt(i) + permOfSub)` lines is  considered O(n) then the equation is:

```
T(n+1)=(n+1)*(n + T(n) + n!*(n+1))
```

T(n) ~ (n*n+2*n-1)*n! i.e., `O(n!*n*n)`

Comment: You are forgetting the +O(n) term at each level for iterating over the existing elements.  This makes your answer off by a factor of n.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the question to include the test program. Basically I increase a count in the innermost loop and print out its value after completion vs N!. Turn out count is always exactly equal to N! * (N-1). For example of the string is 'abc', N! is 3x2x1 = 6, count is 12. I still can't figure out where the N-1 comes from.

Comment: BTW, thanks for pointing out WolframAlpha. I didn't know it could do that. So cool!

Comment: @templatetypedef: It is a habit from python to ignore cost of couple of functions that are implemented in C compared to the cost of pure Python loop

Comment: @templatetypedef it's off by a factor of (n-1) as per my test program; I don't understand why that's the case though nor do I understand the logic behind your assertion that it's off by n. Can you help elaborate? Thank you!

Comment: @auron- The above recurrence assumes a constant amount of work done at each level, but this ignores that each function call has a loop in it that iterates n times.  This means that the recurrence should be nT (n-1) + n.  This changes the result.

Comment: @templatetypedef the loop you mentioned, did you mean the outer (i->str.length) or inner loop (permOfSub : findPermutations) in my code? If the outer, then is it already taken into account as the N in the equation (i.e. N times, x T(N-1) for the permutation call)? If the inner, it's not exactly N, it's whatever number of permutations returned (usually bigger than N); plus, assume that number is M, then shouldn't it be N x (T(N-1) + M)?  Do I miss anything?  Thanks!

Comment: @auron: I might have missed `(n-1)!` multiplier (number of permutations of a string with length `n-1`) i.e., in the simplest case then all string operations are O(1): `T(n) = n*(T(n-1)+(n-1)!)`. The solution is [`n*n!`](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=t%281%29%3D1%2C+t%28n%2B1%29%3D%28n%2B1%29*%28t%28n%29+%2B+n%21%29&x=0&y=0)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: that's it! Thanks for pointing out. My original test program shows (n-1) * n!, but that's because I miss putting count++ in the base case. I've updated the program to include that, and the count is exactly n * n! as you mentioned.  Thanks again for helping out.

Comment: @auron- I was referring to the fact that the inner loop does at least O(1) work per iteration and works for n iterations, so there should be a +n term at the end of the recurrence.