# Algorithm to print String Permutations - Running Time Analysis

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o

I have the following code to print permutations of a given string.
[For simplicity and not to loose focus on what I am trying, lets assume there are not duplicates characters in the string]

```
public static int count = 0;

public static void permute(String soFar, String strLeft) {

    if(strLeft.length() == 1) {
        soFar += strLeft;
        System.out.println(++count + " :: " + soFar);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<strLeft.length(); i++) {
        permute(soFar + strLeft.charAt(i), strLeft.substring(0,i) + strLeft.substring(i+1));
    }
}

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "abcd";
    permute("",input);
}
```

I am trying to figure out the running time of this code.

My chain of thoughts so far:
Trying to write a recurrence,

```
T(n) = n * T(n-1) + O(n) for n > 1
     = 1                 for n = 1
```

There are n! permutations, but the number of recursive calls are greater than n!. In-fact for the example where input string is "abcd" , i.e. 4 characters, the number of calls to the permute function is 65.

Any pointers on how I should go about finding the running time of this code?

Comment: What's greater - the number of calls to the method, or the amount of numbers that it will output during its runtime?

Comment: Duplicate/Similar question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425344/what-is-the-complexity-big-o-of-this-algorithm

Comment: @anorton - yes, this does look like a duplicate. Thanks! I am going through the answer in the other thread and will mark this as closed.

Comment: @AnuragKapur No problem.  Interestingly enough--I just saw that other question no more than 15 minutes ago while researching one of *my* questions.  I thought I was seeing double when your question popped up... `:)`

Comment: Hmm, so the solution on the other thread uses WolframAlpha solution to the recurrence. Does that mean, there isn't an easy way to calculate this recurrence solution on paper?

Comment: Also, the recurrence on the other thread is different. Which is correct? If mine isn't correct, would you be kind enough to explain why? What have I missed?

Comment: @Makoto The number of calls to the method (65) > amount of number that will output (24). More hints please? :)

Comment: Actually...this seems like an infinite loop.  You never deplete `strLeft`.  Instead of thinking of it like a program, approach it like you would writing it down:  how many times do you manipulate the string and produce a new permutation with respect to the size of the string?  That *should* be your Big-O.

Comment: Thanks. However there isn't an infinite loop because the for loop is of finite length. I have actually run this and the programme terminates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first of all, you make redundant calls. If there is only one character left, you emit a solution. But then you will still call `permute` with an empty string and spoils the calling count.

My first improvement would be to add an `else` to the `if` clause.

```
public static void permute(String soFar, String strLeft) {

    if(strLeft.length() == 1) {
        soFar += strLeft;
        System.out.println(++count + " :: " + soFar);
    }
    else {
        for(int i=0; i<strLeft.length(); i++) {
            permute(soFar + strLeft.charAt(i), strLeft.substring(0,i) + strLeft.substring(i+1));
        }
    }
}
```

This cuts down the amount of calls to 41. And to count the number of calls, construct the calling tree and count the nodes. As each call is done by removing one character from the string, there are:
1 calls of length 4,
4 calls of length 3,
12 calls of length 2 and
24 calls of length 1

Which sums up to 41. Voilá.

Comment: Thanks. So the general solution for a problem of size n would be: n!/1! + n!/2! + ... + n!/n!

Comment: I still don't know how to convert the above general solution into corresponding Big-Oh, but it was more important for me to understand a relation representing how the problem or the recursive calls proliferate. So a +1 to your answer and I have marked it as accepted. Thanks!